# How do I see how quickly items are dropping out of memcache?

Tags: memcached

Is there a good way to monitor how quickly items are dropping out of memcache?

Answer (score 1):

I've found this quite useful in the past.. Although probably not quite what you're after.
http://code.google.com/p/memcache-top/

Answer (score 1):

If you telnet to the server and run the 'stats' command you will get the number of evictions since the server started. If you automate this and run it periodically you will be able to track the eviction rate over time, although you will not know exactly what was evicted.

Comment: And by `telnet`, you mean `ssh`, right? :)

Comment: @mattdm nope, he means telnet. Memcached uses telnet for admin stuff =)

Comment: Oh I see. Not telnet to the server system; use telnet to open a tcp connection to the server port.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [phpmemcacheadmin](http://code.google.com/p/phpmemcacheadmin/) like stand-alone monitoring tool to to see both evicted item counts and rates.

[image: phpmemcacheadmin]